# accessing a class in parse using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Just created a class in parse named, universityName 
then created 3 columns named: universityEnrolledName, classEnrolledName, and professorName

i'm attempting to access it in swift and this is what i've been trying

```
    var newUniversity = PFQuery(className: universityName)
    newUniversity.universityEnrolledName = universityEnrolledName
    newUniversity.classEnrolledName = classEnrolledName
    newUniversity.professorName = professorName

    //attempt number 2

    var newUniversity = PFObject(className: universityName)
    newUniversity.universityEnrolledName = self.universityEnrolledName
    newUniversity.classEnrolledName = self.classEnrolledName
    newUniversity.professorName = self.professorName
```

but i can't access the columns universityEnrolledName, classEnrolledName, or professorName

i'm basically 'trying' to allow a user to input the name of their university, name of a class their taking, and the name of the professor.

Comment: Why are you trying to access columns?  PFQuery queries for rows.  You populate the table with rows (PFObjects) that have data for each column.  Those are what you query for, and then you can get the value out of each column for that row.

Comment: i'm basically 'trying' to allow a user to input the name of their university, name of a class their taking, and the name of the professor.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is create a new row.  The easiest way is:

```
var university = PFObject(classname:"universityEnrolledName")
university["universityEnrolledName"] = self.universityEnrolledName
university["classEnrolledName"] = self.classEnrolledName
university["professorName"] = self.professorName
university.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
```

What this is doing is creating a new PFObject with values for each of the columns.  Any column name or PFObject class name must be in quotes, as it is not known by your program.  In your case, your PFObject class appears to be "universityEnrolledName".  See https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Normally what you do in Parse is like this:

```
//attempt number 3

var newUniversity = PFObject(className: universityName)
newUniversity["universityEnrolledName"] = self.universityEnrolledName
```

In that way, your class in Parse is "universityName" and the Column you refer to (in the example above) is "universityEnrolledName"

I hope that helps.

Armin

Comment: Like the "attempt number 3"